# Fisher's exact test: 95% CI or p-value

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, sas, fishers-exact-test

I have run proc freq to test association between two binary variables using the Fisher's exact test. However, the outputs seem contradict to each other as **Two-sided Pr <= P 0.0355** whereas the OR and the 95% Confidence Limits 0.1097 **[0.0022, 1.1380] includes 1**.

This means that p-value shows that they are significantly associated while the 95% CI does not indicate that.

My question is that based on the output from SAS, what should I use: p-value or CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different types of Fisher's exact test, a two-sided Fisher’s exact test using minimum likelihood and the central Fisher’s exact test. The confidance intervals in your output do not match the test is being used. I don't know how to perform in SAS a analysis where CI matches the test but if this should be not possible you can read [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/vignettes/exact2x2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjY48OhlMDhAhUBL1AKHW10AmIQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0JNcqhfEQe_WkGj4BV_jy6) how to perform it in R. The link opens a pdf with package description where the same problem is described as in your question. The name of the R package is exact2x2.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent several hours to read SAS guide. SAS already mentions about this problem and it refers to Agresti (1992). However, I have not seen that it refers to Fay (2009) as you have mentioned about the new way of computing the matching CI. Thus, I think, at this moment, it is available in R to compute the matching CI.

Comment: You are welcome. If it answers your question consider marking it as answered.